# adding label in grid view

Tags: android, gridview, label

I want to add labels for the icons in grid view in Android.I found some answers for this but none worked for me.Most of the time the application get closed forcefully.
Any help will be appreciated.

here's the code that i am using

```
package com.appsdrip16;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);

            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("key", position); 

          //Inflate the layout
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View MyView = li.inflate(R.layout.main, null);

            //View MyView;
            // Add The Text!!!
            TextView tv = (TextView) MyView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_text);
            tv.setText("Item "+ position );

        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }
    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = { 
              R.drawable.icon1, R.drawable.icon2,
              R.drawable.icon3, R.drawable.icon4
             };
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. in which programming language? Also show us what have you tried to help you better.

Comment: i posted my code here.But have no idea about what to do for the main.xml file i mn do i have to use textview and gridview together??

Answer (score 0):

For implementing such Custom gridview, you have to define a custom row XML layout file and then inflate it inside the custom adapter to be used for your GridView with icons and text.